# Trying to send a mail from a .NET 5 console application using SMTP

Tags: c#, .net, email, smtp, gmail

**Context**
I'm developing an application using WPF and .NET 5 for a research institute. The client would like to receive an email when something goes wrong during an experience because it can last several days.

Before adding this feature to the software, I made a simple test program to send an email from a console application and it worked... mostly.

*Disclaimer* : I know there are tons of threads about this subject, and I have read nearly a hundred. The code itself doesn't seem to be the problem and I did setup the google account with two factor authentication (I also tried the "Less secure app" option).

**The problem**
I said the problem doesn't seem to be the code because I actually managed to send emails that way, using my personal gmail address. Problem is, I don't want to use my own address to send mail to the client... So I created an new gmail address and enabled 2FA. And when I try to send an email with the new address I get this in the emitter inbox :

[image]

**What I already tried**
I've tried various recipient and port with the same result. I've looked for this issue on google support, on forums and on youtube but I didn't find anything similar to my problem. I even waited 2 weeks to make sure it wasn't because the address was too recent and judged as "untrustworthy" or something like that.

**The code I used**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        MailAddress to = new MailAddress("recipient@gmail.com");
        MailAddress from = new MailAddress("emitter@gmail.com");
        MailMessage message = new MailMessage(from, to);
        message.Subject = "Using the new SMTP client.";
        message.Body = "Using this new feature, you can send an e-mail message from an application very easily.";
        message.DeliveryNotificationOptions = DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnFailure;
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient
        {
            EnableSsl = true,
            Port = 587,
            Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
            Timeout = 10000,
            DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
            UseDefaultCredentials = false,
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential("emitter@gmail.com", "app-specific-password")
        };

        try
        {
            client.Send(message);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception caught in Main(): {0}",
                  ex.ToString());
        }
        message.Dispose();
}
```

**What I would like**
I just need to be able to send a few emails per day, to one or two contacts, from a WPF application. Nothing fancy. It seems that the two options I got are :

- to find how to create a neutral email address that can use gmail smtp

or

- to find another (easy and free) solution to send emails.

Can you help me with that, please ?

Comment: You can use some SMTP services, as AWS SES

Comment: The link in your screenshot is https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6596. From that, it looks like the *recipient* rejected your email. I don't read enough French to understand the rest, but the problem appears to be the content of your email, and/or who you're sending it to, and not the C# code you use to send it

Comment: @canton7 That link probably indicates the message sending has been blocked, not the recipient. Gmail is picking the messages up as spam and not sending them. The best solution here is to not use Gmail for this in the first place. Pay the small monthly fee for an account.

Comment: For example https://support.google.com/mail/thread/4109104/so-what-really-is-69585-see-https-support-google-com-mail-answer-69585-ref-blocked-emails?hl=en

Comment: @Emanuele Thank you, I'll look into this solution if I decide to go with another SMTP service. To be honest my preferred alternative for now would be to understand my problem, should it only be for the sake of my nerves... ^^'

Comment: I didn't translate the message because it only says : "the message was blocked, to know more...". But what you all are saying concurs with what I was afraid of : the problem might just come from gmail being very sensitive and 'arbitrarily' deciding to reject my email ?

Comment: I looked for a way to "whitelist" the emitter or the mail but I didn't find anything. Do you know if that's even possible ?

Comment: @DavidG Unfortunately it's not my call to make and my superior always want to go for free solutions. In this case, I can understand considering that we might send no more than a few emails per year.

Comment: The truth is that you get what you pay for, and ultimately if your app is sending emails from a Gmail account, your clients are going to think you are extremely unprofessional. How would you feel if the app you paid for did that? Another solution is to get the SMTP details from a config file and let the client add their own. That way they can use their own server and you're not responsible for it.